# MongoDb sum query

Tags: mongodb

For example I have the following data in MongoDB:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("524091f99c49c4c3f66b0e46"), "hour" : 10, "incoming", 100}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5240a045dbeff33c7333aa51"), "hour" : 11, "incoming", 200}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5240a2ecda0d37f35c618aca"), "hour" : 12, "incoming", 300}
```

Now I want to query "SUM the number of incoming between 11 - 12" (the result should be 500), how could I do this using Mongo Shell?

Comment: Check out MongoDB's [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/). In particular, take a look at [`$match`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match), [`$group`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group), and [`$sum`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/sum/#grp._S_sum).

Answer (score 129, accepted):

As llovet suggested, the aggregation framework is the way to go. Here's what your query would look like:

```
db.CollectionNameGoesHere.aggregate({ $match: {
    $and: [
        { hour: { $gte: 11 } },
        { hour: { $lte: 12 } }
    ]
} },
{ $group: { _id : null, sum : { $sum: "$incoming" } } });
```

You can also shape the resulting document to only contain the sum by adding a $project operator at the end of the pipeline, like so:

```
{ $project: { _id: 0, sum: 1 } }
```

Comment: if i want all the fields how do i do it

Comment: then dont use project

Comment: this returns list and can it return dict directly ?

Answer (score 9):

Some examples if you use **mongoose**:

1. Calculate total sum of product prices :

```
Products.aggregate([ { $match: {} }, { $group:
  { _id : null, sum : { $sum: "$Price" } }
}])
.then(res => console.log(res[0].sum));
```

( `{ $match: {} },` can be removed. )

---

2. Sum of Product's prices in each category:

```
Products.aggregate([{ $group:
  { _id : '$Category', sum : { $sum: "$Price" } }
}])
.then(res => console.log(res));
```