# Nestjs- How to sum up all the number values of a particular collection of mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, nestjs

I am working on nestjs and I have a collection where 5 documents are saved and each document has a property name 'price'. I want to fetch price property from every document and need to sum up all and shows that sum as an output. How do I achieve this?

Comment: It´s hard to guess what you really want to achieve without any line of code. Could you provide what you tried so far? Makes it so much easier for people to help you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoDb sum query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18969916/mongodb-sum-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use aggregate

```
.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: '',
      sumPrices: { $sum: '$price' }
  }
])
```